# .NET Core 2.1 Lambda function fails at runtime with FileNotFoundException for netstandard

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, .net-standard

I have a .NET Core 2.1 Lambda function. The csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="chromium.br" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="chromium.br">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="amazon.lambda.logging.aspnetcore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="amazon.lambda.serialization.json" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="microsoft.extensions.logging" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="mono.posix.NETStandard" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="puppeteersharp" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="HeadlessChromium.Puppeteer.Lambda.Dotnet">
      <HintPath>..\HeadlessChromium.Puppeteer.Lambda.Dotnet\HeadlessChromium.Puppeteer.Lambda.Dotnet.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The project compiles, but at runtime (i.e. in the Lambda environment), the application fails with the message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified
```

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the HeadlessChromium.Puppeteer.Lambda.Dotnet.dll I used was compiled against .NET Standard 2.1. Using the .NET Core 2.1 DLL instead solved the problem.